# Symfony 2.4 ESI bug? (Debian 7 + nginx + Varnish + PHP 5.4 / PHP 5.5: ESI doesn't work - surprising PHP behavior)

Tags: php, symfony, esi

## Basics

I made a very simple test action:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/public/debug/varnish", name="debug_varnish")
 * @Template
 */
public function varnishAction()
{
    return [];
}
```

```twig
{# varnish.html.twig #}
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Layout</h1>
    <hr />
    {{ render_esi(controller('TestBundle:Debug:esi')) }}
</body>
</html>
```

The included action and twig isn't important now.

## The test

The Varnish needs the `Surrogate-Control: content="ESI/1.0"` header in the response. Look what happens:

```
curl -H 'host:www.domain.com' -H 'Surrogate-Capability: abc=ESI/1.0' http://127.0.0.1:8080/public/debug/varnish
```

The response:

```html
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Layout</h1>
    <hr />
    <esi:include src="/_proxy?_path=_format%3Dhtml%26_locale%3Den_US%26_controller%3DTestBundle%253ADebug%253Aesi" onerror="continue" />
</body>
</html>
```

Everythings alright! But look the headers:

```
curl -I -H 'host:www.domain.com' -H 'Surrogate-Capability: abc=ESI/1.0' http://127.0.0.1:8080/public/debug/varnish
```

The output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1~dotdeb.1
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=k8jii3gkrha1js7edbbbqjjh32; path=/
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date: Tue, 18 Feb 2014 11:21:04 GMT
```

There isn't `Surrogate-Control` header!

## \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpCache\Esi class

There is a very-very simple function, which add `Surrogate-Control` header, if content contains `<esi:include` string:

```php
/**
 * Adds HTTP headers to specify that the Response needs to be parsed for ESI.
 *
 * This method only adds an ESI HTTP header if the Response has some ESI tags.
 *
 * @param Response $response A Response instance
 */
public function addSurrogateControl(Response $response)
{
    if (false !== strpos($response->getContent(), '<esi:include')) {
        $response->headers->set('Surrogate-Control', 'content="ESI/1.0"');
    }
}
```

But it doesn't! The if is "true". When I call with this:

```php
public function addSurrogateControl(Response $response)
{
    var_dump(false !== strpos($response->getContent(), '<esi:include'));
    if (false !== strpos($response->getContent(), '<esi:include')) {
        echo "before add header\n";
        $response->headers->set('Surrogate-Control', 'content="ESI/1.0"');
        echo "after add header\n";
    }
    echo "after if"
}
```

```bash
curl -H 'host:www.domain.com' -H 'Surrogate-Capability: abc=ESI/1.0' http://127.0.0.1:8080/public/debug/varnish
```

The response:

```html
(bool) true
before add header
after add header
after if
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Layout</h1>
    <hr />
    <esi:include src="/_proxy?_path=_format%3Dhtml%26_locale%3Den_US%26_controller%3DTestBundle%253ADebug%253Aesi" onerror="continue" />
</body>
</html>
```

```bash
curl -I -H 'host:www.domain.com' -H 'Surrogate-Capability: abc=ESI/1.0' http://127.0.0.1:8080/public/debug/varnish
```

The output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1~dotdeb.1
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=k8jii3gkrha1js7edbbbqjjh32; path=/
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date: Tue, 18 Feb 2014 11:21:04 GMT
```

*WHERE IS THE `Surrogate-Control` HEADER?* :-o

More tests:

```php
public function addSurrogateControl(Response $response)
{
    // [1]
    if (false !== strpos($response->getContent(), '<esi:include')) {
        // [2]
    }
    // [3]
}
```

With `$response->headers->set('Surrogate-Control', 'content="ESI/1.0"');` and (!!!) `header('Test: test OK')`:

- [1] place: WORK!
- [2] original place: doesn't work :(
- [3] place: WORK!

Ok. So if ANY header modification is in the `IF`, it doesn't work. *Why?*

## The magic

When I change the `$response->getContent()` with `'test <esi:include test'` in the `if` condition, then everthing works fine. The `Response` class `getContent()` function:

```php
public function getContent()
{
    return $this->content;
}
```

I don't understand :-/